# Como descargo archivos alojados en Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Buen día,
Estoy un poco desorientado ya que necesito que mis usuarios descarguen información alojada desde mi proyecto en codeigniter, ya sean imagenes, documentos entre otros, entonces me preguntaba si existe algún Helper o Liberia para descargar archivos alojados desde mi proyecto en codeigniter ?
Muchas gracias

Comment: a que te refieres con poder descargar? un simple a es decir una etiqueta ancla al elemento no sirve? o en que paso estas atorado?

Comment: Gracias por contestar
Por ejemplo, yo quiero que mis usuarios descarguen programas empresariales que esten alojados desde mi pagina pero no se con que helper o libreria puedo hacer eso

Comment: @DiegoPaez si lo tienes almacenado directamente en tu sitio web basta con agregar el enlace directo al archivo o ¿como es que quieres hacerlo?.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes emplear el download_helper:

```
force_download('ruta/del/archivo.zip', NULL);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html